# Is it possible to create a an app which can fetch Google Analytics data periodically without any manual intervention after the first verification?

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

The hassle is, i do not want to download or generate key manually and then feed it to my code. 
And the reason is, i do not want to do this technical things to be done by any non-tech person(client). (i.e. Creating a Key from Developer Console and Download it and Give permission from Dashboard)

I want to make an application which run without any manual intervention once the first step is completed successfully.

Is it possible for client side application? Or Server side (It will be the best)? (compass.co is just asking for google profile login to get analytics data... How does it works?)

Comment: Check out the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) for this app the client (you) need only sign in once and as long as you don't clear your cookies you will be able to return to the app again and again. Perhaps describe the use case of your application and people might be able to help you better. Generally the developer needs to go through the trouble of setting up auth, but the end user does not need to know anything beyond signing into and granting permission to you application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if you create a service account and get a key.

> *Service accounts are useful for automated, offline, or scheduled access to Google Analytics data for your own account. For example, to build a live dashboard of your own Google Analytics data and share it with other users.*

You can then use this to authenticate with the google analytics core reporting API and use in a server side app to retrieve google analytics data.

The following links should help and the second one has examples in the language of you choice.

[Creating GA service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/authorization#service_accounts)

[Authorising Using A Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests)

Comment: Thanks, #bamdan, for answer. I just hope you had gone through the description of question. As i have mentioned... The hassle is, i do not want to download or generate key manually and then feed it to my code. And the reason is, i do not want to do this technical things to be done by any non-tech person(client). (i.e. Creating a Key from Developer Console and Download it and Give permission from Dashboard)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't understand. This is a once off authentication. You can then build your app/dashboard and non tech person doesn't need to do anything. I thought that is what  you wanted rather than the other authenticate methods which require more steps.

Comment: That's totally okay @bamdan, i am novice in this stuffs. If you still have any better flow.., You are most welcome to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the data on a spreadsheet: you could use [this add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on).

Otherwise, you could develop your own version using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) and [Analytics Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics). Once developed, it could be used similar to the previous plugin by anyone with no knowledge of computing. This would allow you to customise and simplify the workflow as much as needed.

[This article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script) has a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this automatic data pull.

Apps Script allows you to run your script/workflow manually whenever you want, periodically time-based with a time trigger or by request by running the app.

As per integration with your own app: App Scripts is contained within itself. You can create a full app there and integrate as many parts as you want. However, you cannot easily iframe nor integrate on other apps.

However, it can push data to spreadsheets. Once contained there, the data can be accessed via JSON and used as a backend ([article](https://coderwall.com/p/duapqq/use-a-google-spreadsheet-as-your-json-backend)).

Comment: Thanks @fvbuendia, for the answer and attention. So, according to this App Scripts, is it possible to plugin that to any of my application? Also one more thing i keeping me confused that, can i push App Scripts programmatically ? And fetch data in json format?

Comment: Yes, you can run the workflow either manually, periodically with a time trigger or on a request running to the app. As per integration: App Scripts is contained within itself. You can create a full app there, but you cannot iframe nor integrate easily on your app. However, what you could do is push the data to a spreadsheet. Then, use the spreadsheet as your JSON backend for your app: https://coderwall.com/p/duapqq/use-a-google-spreadsheet-as-your-json-backend